# How to run okta auth sample for php

Tags: php

I download sample code from github
https://github.com/okta/samples-php/tree/develop/okta-hosted-login
and run it following guide.
when I start server, it shows this issue.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Jose\KeyConverter\gmp_strval()
```

if I refresh page it says

```
Could not exchange code for an access token
```

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate a token on okta project manage panel.
Copy it to config file in your project

For example:

```
AUTH_TOKEN:USDJFO34500YFDFSDF2345_W4>%23*^&FG
APP_ID: YOUR APP ID
```

Comment: I tried but still same issue. but where can I find the app id?

Comment: select your app from the developer console and you can find it on project setting's tab->security->app->app id

Comment: what is your backend server?

Comment: it is php server. I am using laravel.8